# How can I determine if my DLL is being registered or executing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-4.0, regasm

I have an IE add-on I'm developing in C# VS2010 .NET4. It seems that when the DLL is registered (ie installed) it executes the main constructor, and from there a lot of code that has no business running at that point in time. Is there a way I can determine if the DLL is in the process of being registered vs actually executing so I can avoid this code being executed?

It is registered via RegAsm

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add system beeps or trace to log file (with time stamps) on places where you need to know if code is being executed.

Comment: I know the code is being executed, that isn't the issue. The issue is I need to know if it is being executed in the context of being registered with regasm, or loaded into IE. For example, the main class constructor calls a toolbar constructor, which creates a form used for logging. When regasm is run to register the dll, that window appears and the whole thing hangs until it finally crashes regasm. I need to know "I'm being executed by regasm" so I can then NOT call the toolbar constructor.